# Will 505 directory permissions allow google to execute a file in that directory?

Tags: permissions

If a directory is 505 permissions and all the files in the directory are read only would google be able to execute a file in that directory? What about 0555

Comment: so it goes...r-xr-xr-x

Answer (score 1):

Google doesn't "execute files". They make requests to your web server. Whether this will work or not is primarily dependent on your web server configuration, not on file permissions.